# How do I perform arithmetic operations on an array

Tags: java, arrays, math

This is what I have at the moment - I am wanting to divide all the values in letterCount array by the length  of the string and then store these values in a new array called calculatedFreq.

Is there a way that I can do this?

EDIT: I am aware that the calculatedFreq should be a double but this seems to cause even more problems.

Comment: Instead of calculatedFreq  = letterCount/s.length(); try calculatedFreq [i] = letterCoun[i]t/s.length();

Comment: Your indentation is confusing. And I suggest to always use braces with `for` and `while` loops and `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I perform arithmetic operations on an array?

You cannot.

Array is an object, and you cannot apply [arithmetic operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) on objects, as Java arithmetic operators perform addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and modulo.

You can, however, fetch the elements from the array, and apply arithmetic operations on them, IFF, they support arithmetic operations (e.g. they are some things you can add, subtract, etc.).

Do:

```java
calculatedFreq[i] = letterCount[i]/s.length();
```

instead, so that your code will look like:

```java
public class Brutus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] letterCount = new int[26];
        String s = args[0].replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
            letterCount[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
        System.out.println(letterCount[0]);
        int[] calculatedFreq = new int[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < letterCount.length; i++)
            calculatedFreq[i] = letterCount[i]/s.length(); //<--modification here
    }
}
```

Also, it is unclear why you define constant 26 to be the length of your array. Maybe it would have been better to do something like:

```java
String s = args[0].replace(" ", "").toLowerCase();
int[] letterCount = new int[s.length()];
```

as this way, you will have the array of exactly the size of your input length (after replacement and etc.).

Comment: This results in: error: ';' expected and error: not a statement both on the line that you recommended

Comment: Many thanks for both of your solutions however im still running into issues. It sompiles fine however if i run $java Brutus "hi" I get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2

Comment: If am not mistaken if you have int[] letterCount = new int[s.length()]; with a string like "z" you would get of of bounds

Comment: because of s.charAt(i) - 'a'

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Yes, but since letterCount is being used to count the letter it has to be as big as the max ascii doc - 'a', which will depend of what is the user input. But since OP is doing s.charAt(i) - 'a' I would assume that it is from a to z

Comment: @dreamcrash it was `s.length()` at first.. didn't notice you've edited it; and yes, `letterCount` might cause out of bounds.. but again, it can also be that `letterCount[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;` will be a problem here.. disregarding on what you're iterating - letterCount or length. Generally, this is not the good design, but I think the design should be decided by OP, not by us. He/she should now have enough information to tackle their initial point.

Comment: Yes, I made that mistake sorry, I meant to change the second loop end up changing the first. Yes, OP defined 26 because it is the number of letters in the English alphabet.